# Lightning: New way to detect a change in the URL (effective Summer '18)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura-locationchange

Now that aura:locationChange event no longer works with the new URL format ( effective from Summer '18 release. Reference [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_events.htm)), is there a way to detect a change in the URL using lightning events or any other mechanism?

```
    handleLocationChange: function (component, event, helper) {
        var location = event.getParam("token");//this returns null now with the Summer '18 release.
        if (location != '/n/my_fav_URL') {
            //do some {!stuff}
        } else {
            //do some {!NOT(stuff)}
        }
    }
```

I see that lightning:navigation and pageReference object don't really provide a straight way to detect the URL changes like aura:locationChange did.

Answer (score 4):

For Lightning communities only:

```html
<aura:handler event="forceCommunity:routeChange" action="{!c.handleRouteChange}"
```

allows you to do so.

For LEX, in app, I dont know if there is a clean way to do so, maybe someone else can provide feedback.

I know you can use setInterval to constantly check the url and log any url changes by leveraging [Change Handlers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_data_change.htm) to perform an action based on the change taking place.

Comment: Thanks @glls. Sorry, I should have mentioned that I am looking for LEX app, not for communities. For the setInterval comment, I think it is probably a better idea to use the aura:locationChange event instead of constantly polling the URL for a change. Fortunately, the aura:locationChange event hasn't been deprecated. It just no longer works as intended with the token returned being empty. For now, I will rely on aura:locationChange event coupled with window.location.pathname. Thank you.